# Who was Dalzell? $\pi$ < 22/7

Tags: math-history, pi

The Dalzell-Integral reads:

$$0<\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

It proves that $\pi<\frac{22}{7}$.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80).
It was introduced by D.P.Dalzell in 1944 (see Wikipedia).

My question: **Who was D.P. Dalzell? Any information on him or her?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Paul J. Nahin's book *Inside Interesting Integrals*, p. 24, it is said

> The author of the 1944 paper that first published this gem was D. P.
>   Dalzell, a curious fellow who is mostly a ghost in the history of
>   mathematics. All of the modern references to Dalzell’s integral make
>   no mention of the man, himself, even though he wrote a number of high
>   quality mathematical papers and had an excellent reputation among
>   mathematicians. Dalzell didn’t help his cause by his habit of always
>   using his initials. In fact, he was Donald Percy Dalzell (1898–1988),
>   who graduated in 1921 from St. John’s College, Cambridge, in
>   mathematics and mechanical sciences. He received an MA degree in 1926,
>   and his career was not as a mathematician but rather as a chartered
>   engineer (a term used in England for a masters level professional
>   engineer). He worked for a number of years for the Standard Telephones
>   and Cables Company in London, and had two patents on electrical
>   communication cables. The only known photograph of him is the one on
>   the MacTutor math web-site (taken at the 1930 Edinburgh Mathematical
>   Society Colloquium at St. Andrews).

Comment: Wow! That book of Nahin looks like a lot of fun...

Comment: @L.Milla That book is a masterpiece.. and I sometimes forgot to breathe during my nights of reading that text.. It's simply more than just "fun".. It's Nahin..